# apt pinning not working

Tags: apt

I am trying to setup pinning for some non-free firmware, but it is not working.

## output of `apt-cache policy`

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google LLC,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11-updates,o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=bullseye-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11,o=Debian,a=stable-security,n=bullseye-security,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=11.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 -10 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=11.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

## config

### `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib
# deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib

# bullseye-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib
# deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib
```

### `etc/apt/sources.list.d/apt-source-list-non-free.list`

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye non-free contrib
```

## `/etc/apt/preferences.d/apt-preferences-non-free-policy`

```
#Explanation: don't install non-free, except some firmware

Package: *
Pin: release c=non-free
Pin-Priority: -10

Package: *
Pin: release c=contrib
Pin-Priority: -10
```

## `/etc/apt/preferences.d/firmware-linux-nonfree`

```
Explanation: Enable package from non-free tree
Package: firmware-linux-nonfree
Pin: release o=Debian,a=bullseye,l=Debian,c=non-free
Pin-Priority: 600
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:
edit the `Pin:` line for the package to read `Pin: release c=non-free`.

## Explanation

Remove un-necessary stuff. I don't fully understand the format, I copied the config from somewhere. I can't find good explanations. So we are left with simple is better.

I hope someone else can help to explain more.